# How to make bootable pendrive to install ubuntu os?

Tags: usb, usb-drive

I am a newbie to all of this stuff.

Initially I had a OS CD of Ubuntu 10.4 version. I never tried to install it. Now I have lost my CD somewhere. Earlier I copied the content to my laptop. When I tried to install by copying to another CD/pendrive it didn't install.

Now i am using Windows. But I would like to install Ubuntu, because everyone said that Linux/Ubuntu is an amazing OS.

So I searched in google for a solution. With Unetbootin, pendrive linux, I can make a bootable pendrive to install. But Unetbootin asks for an ISO-image. I did many experiment and wastes more than 9 CD's. I have no experience with that. Where can I get the ISO-image?
Actually, what is an ISO-image?

Comment: Have you seen the official guide for creating and installing through bootable USB: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows  ?

Comment: Is it possible to create image from extracted files

Comment: @abcd yes its possible, but it won't be bootable. You need to manage the configure flag and required system files manually.

Answer (score 3):

You can download copy of ubuntu iso at http://www.ubuntu.com.

For a pen drive installation,
The motherboard has to support booting from a USB flash/pen/key drive. Please consult your BIOS manufacture reference for more details.

An image is a copy of a cd/dvd that can be directly used for burning/mounting. Its more like a zip file or you can say a single file representation of a whole cd/dvd. There are some more features. Like - Copying ***contents*** of a cd/dvd and burning them ***won't make the cd/dvd bootable***.  There are special flags with image file, that causes the cd to be bootable after burning.

Answer (score 0):

We have study your own This informative article and that I have known numerous data using this site.For more info, an individual can turn to This specific site.. 
http://www.datagifted.com/how-to-make-bootable-usb-or-pendrive/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score -2):

You can use this tool for creating your bootable USB drive
it can be used from  Windows / Linux /Mac

It can also directly download the iso file to create the bootable usb stick for you.

[unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: did you read his question at all? He doesn't have the image.

Comment: yeah, either the question was edited or I was temporarily blind when answering