# How can I make my pendrive bootable (My UBUNTU copy is not an ISO file)?

Tags: installation, usb-drive, bootloader

I have UBUNTU 12.04 LTS OS. Its not an image file/ISO image. I have searched a lot about how to make a pendrive bootable in order to install ubuntu, but everywhere they assume that I have ISO file. Even I've seen [How to make bootable pendrive to install ubuntu os?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153002/how-to-make-bootable-pendrive-to-install-ubuntu-os). So I'm confused as I don't know how to get boot manager to make my pendrive bootable.

**REMEMBER: My UBUNTU copy is NOT an ISO image file**.

*Simply copy-pasting those ubuntu files is not working*.

Comment: You should re-download the ISO from th Ubuntu website. If you got a copy that isn't an ISO, it's probably not the correct download, or even official, for that matter.

Comment: If what you have is not an ISO file... *what **do** you have?*

Comment: @EliahKagan Its actually a folder containing all necessary files and folders where there is an wubi.exe installer file also

Comment: ok @Catbuntu I will try, actually I've downloaded it from torrent.

Answer (score 1):

To install Ubuntu through an USB stick, you need to download the ISO image from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download). Select 32-bit or 64-bit depending on if your processor is 64-bit capable, but if you choose 32-bit it will always work. See [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/32bit_and_64bit) for more information.

After downloading the ISO file, download and install [PendriveLinux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/). Once it's installed, open it, and select your version of Ubuntu from the first dropdown menu:

[image: PendriveLinux]

After selecting it, click on the `Browse` button and select the ISO image you downloaded:

[image: PendriveLinux]

Finally, choose the USB drive (the letter; may be `D:\`, `K:\`, etc.) and click on the `Create` button:

[image: PendriveLinux]

Once it's burnt, just configure your BIOS to [boot from the USB](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/tipstricks/ht/bootusbflash.htm) and [install Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-desktop-latest).

---

- See also [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236599/how-to-create-a-bootable-usb-stick-on-windows-but-to-install-on-linux) about burning USB images.
- Font and images: [Ubuntu Wiki](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)